# Using a stable appium, What combination of chromedriver and android can operate?

Tags: android, jenkins, cucumber, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing a web test that is running on a android platform. 
If I execute it in local no problem, but if I do since Jenkins, there are the following error message:

error:

```
Chromedriver: Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code null, signal SIGTERM
Chromedriver stopped unexpectedly on us, shutting down then calling back up with the on-die callback
```

error:

```
Chromedriver: Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device emulator-6399 is not online
```

error:

```
Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device emulator-6399 is not online
```

I think that mistake may be due to incompatibility between versions, but I have tried several versions of *chrome, chromedriver, appium and android,* and I couldn't fix it.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: I could get a fix by monitoring chromedriver all the time during test execution, chromedriver becomes unresponsive while switching back to webview from natiove_app. I developed a small piece of code available at https://github.com/mi2pankaj/chromeDriverHandler, it has solved my all problems, just add this jar chromedriverHandler.jar to your project and use ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().start(); in your beforeclass / beforetest and ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().stop(); in your afterclass / aftertest